# Folder Distribution Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I encountered this problem in my combinatorics textbook and am confused even though I have been given the solution. The problem is as stated:
The office assistant is distributing supplies. In how many ways can he distribute 18 identical folders among four office employees: Audrey, Bart, Cecilia, and Darren with the additional restriction that Bart and Darren can get 0 folders while Audrey and Cecilia need to get at least 1?

The answer is C(19,3). However, when I attempted this problem, my answer was C(19,1). My reasoning was to add the number of folders plus the number of dividers (k=4-1=3) for a total of 21 spaces where either a folder or divider could go. I then fixed two dividers in the first two positions and got C(19,1). Clearly this is incorrect. Could you explain why and also explain the correct answer?

Comment: I expect you meant to say that $B,D$ get at least $0$.  If so, then it's best to first hand $A,C$ one each, so now you have to distribute $17$ folders to $4$ people in any way you like (including $0's$ to some if you want).

Comment: Correction:  Sorry, after you hand two to $A,C$ you have $18-2=16$ left, not $17$ as I wrote.

Comment: If you really meant that $B,D$ get $0$ then you are handing the $18$ folders to two people such that they both get at least $1$.  $A$, say, can get $1,2,\cdots, 17$ so the answer is $17$ in that case.  But, as I said, I doubt you meant to require that $B,D$ get $0$.

Comment: oh haha, you’re right. i misread the question. b,d are allowed to get 0 but a,c are not. thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hand both Audrey and Cecilia a folder.  That leaves us with $18 - 2 = 16$ folders to distribute to Audrey, Bart, Cecilia, and Darren without restriction.  The number of ways this can be done is the number of solutions of the equation
$$a + b + c + d = 16 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $a, b, c, d$ represent, respectively, the number of additional folders received by Audrey, Bart, Cecilia, and Darren.

A particular solution of this equation corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of $16$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $a = 4, b = 5, c = 7, d = 0$, in which case Audrey receives a total of $4 + 1 = 5$ folders, Bart also receives five folders, Cecilia receives a total of $7 + 1 = 8$ folders, and poor Darren receives none.  The number of such solutions is
$$\binom{16 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{19}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the nineteen positions required for $16$ ones and $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

As discussed in the comments, your answer was based on a misreading of the question since zero is not the same as at least zero.